# Pop up notification is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, notifications, react-spring

I wanted to display a pop up notification whenever there is a message from server .
here is a implementation of popup notification

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { X } from "react-feather";
import { useTransition } from "@react-spring/web";
import { Message, Button, Content, Life } from "./styles";

let id = 0;
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { X } from "react-feather";
import { useTransition } from "@react-spring/web";
import { Message, Button, Content, Life } from "./styles";

let id = 0;

export function MessageHub({ children, timeout = 3000 }) {
  const refMap = useRef(new WeakMap());
  const cancelMap = useRef(new WeakMap());
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const transitions = useTransition(items, {
    from: { opacity: 0, height: 0, life: "100%" },
    keys: (item) => item.key,
    enter: (item) 
export function MessageHub({ children, timeout = 3000 }) {
  const refMap = useRef(new WeakMap());
  const cancelMap = useRef(new WeakMap());
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const transitions = useTransition(items, {
    from: { opacity: 0, height: 0, life: "100%" },
    keys: (item) => item.key,
    enter: (item) => async (next, cancel) => {
      cancelMap.current.set(item, cancel);
      await next({ opacity: 1, height: refMap.current.get(item).offsetHeight });
      await next({ life: "0%" });
    },
    leave: [{ opacity: 0 }, { height: 0 }],
    onRest: (_, ctrl, item) => {
      setItems((state) => state.filter((i) => i.key !== item.key));
    },
    config: (_, index, phase) =>
      phase === "enter" && index === "life"
        ? { duration: timeout }
        : { tension: 125, friction: 20, precision: 0.1 },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    children((msg) => {
      setItems((state) => [...state, { key: id++, msg }]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {transitions(({ life, ...style }, item) => (
        <Message style={style} key={item.key}>
          <Content ref={(ref) => ref && refMap.current.set(item, ref)}>
            <Life style={{ right: life }} />
            <p>{item.msg}</p>
            <Button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (cancelMap.current.has(item) && life.get() !== "0%")
                  cancelMap.current.get(item)();
              }}
            >
              <X size={18} />
            </Button>
          </Content>
        </Message>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

and its working fine as i checked with and it rendered a test notification on initial render.

```
<MessageHub timeout={3000}> {(add) => {  add("Test notification");            }} </MessageHub>
```

But when i make it to render when ever there is server response . it does nothing even after successful message from server . Here is implementation of it .

```
const SendButton = ({ updateServerResponse }) => {
  const { configuration, updateConfiguration } = useConfig();
  const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log(configuration);

    try {
      let POST_URL =
        import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL + import.meta.env.VITE_SEND_PASTE;
      const response = await axios.post(POST_URL, configuration);

      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log(response.data);
        updateServerResponse(response.data); // update on server response
      } else {
        console.error(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending POST request:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Send</button>
    </>
  );
};
export const Header = () => {
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState(null);
  const updateResponse = (message) => {
    setServerResponse(message);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="header">
        <ExpiryTime></ExpiryTime>
        <DocFormat></DocFormat>
        <PasswordInput></PasswordInput>
        <SendButton updateServerResponse={updateResponse} />

        <MessageHub timeout={3000}>
          {(add) => {
            add(serverResponse);
            setServerResponse(null);
          }}
        </MessageHub>
        {/* <MessageHub timeout={3000}>
          {(add) => {
            add("Test notification"); // Works ..
          }}
        </MessageHub> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Here is logs]

I wanted to know why there is no notification , even though i updated the state .Do i need to do differently .